# Как сменить фон одновременно у двух activity при нажатии одной кнопки

Tags: java, android, activity

Хочу поменять фон сразу двух (ну или трёх) `activity` при этом нажав на одну кнопку. Вроде про обработчиков нажатий кнопки что-то знаю, но с этим разобраться не могу.

Comment: кнопка при этом нажимается из какой-то активити? Все 2 или 3 активити уже запущены на момент смены фона в них или они не обязательно должны быть запущенными?

Comment: да, кнопка нажимается из первой активити. Все 2, 3 активити уже запущены.

Comment: фактически вы можете назвать мне темы которые помогут мне в этой задаче и я сам разберусь, так сказать, частично помочь

Comment: При клике на кнопку сохраняйте в `SharedPreferences` тему, при запуске активности до `setContentViеw` берите ее и ставьте активности стиль в зависимости от нее

Comment: То есть нужно взять свой стиль из первого activity, сохранить его при щелчке кнопки в SharedPreferences, а затем при запуске другого activity, установить в нём уже сохранный стиль из первого.Я правильно вас понял @Flippy ?

Comment: @Стефан Чагай, да, совершенно правильно. Удачи! :)